# Can I use a regular Gmail account for Laravel email?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am using Laravel 5.5 and am building a contact form which must email me to my personal Gmail account. I have a Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "530" error and I set up my app password in Gmail and inserted it in my .env file. But I am unable to switch off/on my less secure apps as I have a regular Gmail account. I need an administrator to get access to less secure apps settings? Any advice on this? I have researched and can't find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your mail configuration `.env` (**without** the real password of course)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any post mail service that is maintained by Laravel, in general it is SMTP protocol.

For using Gmail account as email box you need generate additional access to this account apart default user access.

As I remember correct you can get that inside Gmail in section "Access settings and confidence". Then Gmail will generate you the numeric code which you should add to `.env` file with name of email.